# Can't calculate the area of regular polygon - wrong result using the tangent formula

Tags: java, trigonometry

I have this method for calculating regular polygon area:

```
    public double getArea()  {
        return (sideLength *
            sideLength * sides) /
            (4 * Math.tan(180 / (double) sides));
    }
```

for `sideLength` and `sides` both being equal to 10 it returns `-219.816218`.
" 
However this online calculator: https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/regular-polygon-area
returns 769.4. What is wrong with my method? The formula I use is specified [here](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonregulararea.html)
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to trigonometric functions are defined on radians, not degrees. Use `Math.toRadians` to convert the angle in degrees to radians - like this:

```
Math.tan(Math.toRadians(180 / (double) sides))
```

Or do this computation in radians to start with.

```
Math.tan(Math.PI / sides)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following return statement

```
return (sideLength  * sideLength  * sides) / (4 * Math.tan((180 / sides) * 3.14159 / 180));
```

Here, `*(3.14159 / 180)` is added to convert the area from `degree` converted to `radians`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Math.tan` function uses radians as it's default unit of measure. Use this instead:

```
(4*Math.tan(Math.PI/180 * 180/(double) sides))
```